# Windows Phone physical device for testing my software

Tags: 8.0, 8.1

I am currently developing apps for Windows Phone 8.1 and I am using the emulator for testing purposes. I have decided to buy a Windows Phone device for running my apps instead as that will be more efficient with feature that aren't available in emulator.

Which phone will allow to take advantage of most Windows Phone 8.1 features for development (such as sensors, NFC and so on)? Should I buy a smartphone with a memory card slot? Knowing that I will use it too as a personal phone for daily usage.

Comment: This site is for questions about using Windows Phone. Development questions should go on Stack Overflow where more developers will see them. I think you should get a phone with the new SensorCore hardware to keep your options open though - 63x, 73x, 83x, 930, 1320, 1520 iirc.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd always go for a "Nokia" (now Microsoft) device, as they're currently the most reliable ones to get further updates.

For development it does depend on what type of apps you're going to build and what features you need to be able to test on the phone (like you said, NFC and stuff).

You might want to consider buying a cheaper phone with a weaker processor and only 512 MB RAM. If your apps perform well on those devices, you wont have any problems with the flagship phones.

I'd propably go with the Lumia 630 or 635 as a pure dev device.

However, as a daily driver I really enjoy my Lumia 930 / Icon.

Comment: Is it better to get a Nokia device with SD slot ? @Thomas

Comment: If you want to check how your app behaves on slower memory, such as SD card, yes. Otherwise, it's not necessary.

Comment: second that. perhaps interesting if your app is really big and/or needs to perform really well, like games.